# Need Python 3.4 version of print() from __future__

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, printing, flush

Currently, when I

`from __future__ import print_function`

from Python 2.7.6, I apparently get a version of print() prior to the addition of the `flush` keyword argument, which went in Python 3.3 according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print).  The Python3 installed in my system (Ubuntu) is Python 3.4, and I verified its print() function has the `flush` argument.

How do I import the `print()` function from 3.4? 
From where is `__future__` getting the older print function?

Comment: Did you just not import the print function with the flush argument?

Comment: How did you even know that it was trying to import a function from 3.4?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot get the version from 3.4 imported into Python 2.7, no. Just flush `sys.stdout` manually after printing:

```
import sys

print(...)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Or you can create a wrapper function around `print()` if you have to have something that accepts the keyword argument:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
try:
    # Python 3
    import builtins
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    import __builtin__ as builtins


def print(*args, **kwargs):
    sep, end = kwargs.pop('sep', ' '), kwargs.pop('end', '\n')
    file, flush = kwargs.pop('file', sys.stdout), kwargs.pop('flush', False)
    if kwargs:
        raise TypeError('print() got an unexpected keyword argument {!r}'.format(next(iter(kwargs))))
    builtins.print(*args, sep=sep, end=end, file=file)
    if flush:
        file.flush()
```

This creates a replacement version that'll work just the same as the version in 3.3 and up.

Comment: Great work-around; I guess `__future__` things are whatever happened to be packaged with that version of Python 2.x?

Comment: `__future__` imports change syntax parsing.  This one disables recognition of `print` as a keyword.  That allows normal access to the builtin `print()` function that is always present  but normally masked by recognition of `print` as keyword.  Without the `__future__` import, it can be accessed with `import __builtin__ as b; b.__dict__['print']`.

Comment: @Pete: indeed, I was being imprecise. `from __future__` imports are syntax flags; the parser and compiler alter behaviour. The `print()` function is just a built-in in Python 2, but you cannot normally use it because `print` is a reserved keyword and a statement. With the import, the compiler removes that keyword reservation and statement.

Comment: why can't you import the one from 3.4?

Comment: @CharlieParker because it is a built-in function defined in C code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how do I see what I am even importing? I also have a import future print statement and its not recognizing flush.

Comment: @MartijnPieters why does it matter if its a C function defined in C code? It seems that we are still importing it and using it regardless of that.

Comment: @CharlieParker: `__future__` imports don't actually import anything in the usual sense.  Doing `from __future__ import print_function` is like telling Python 2.7 "I want to use `print` differently".  It doesn't actually load any code from Python 3.  It just tells Python 2.7 to use a different "mode" that is already built into Python 2.7.